# Map reduce in RavenDb

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

**Update 1** , following Ayende's answer

This is my first journey into RavenDb and to experiment with it I wrote a small map/ reduce, but unfortunately the result is empty?

I have around 1.6 million documents loaded into RavenDb

A document:

```
public class Tick
{
    public DateTime Time;
    public decimal Ask;
    public decimal Bid;
    public double AskVolume;
    public double BidVolume;
}
```

and wanted to get Min and Max of Ask over a specific period of Time.

The collection by Time is defined as:

```
var ticks = session.Query<Tick>().Where(x => x.Time > new DateTime(2012, 4, 23) && x.Time < new DateTime(2012, 4, 24, 00, 0, 0)).ToList();
```

Which gives me 90280 documents, so far so good.

But then the map/ reduce:

```
Map = rows => from row in rows 
                          select new
                          {
                              Max = row.Bid,
                              Min = row.Bid, 
                              Time = row.Time,
                              Count = 1
                          };

Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by new{ result.MaxBid, result.Count} into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Max = g.Key.MaxBid,
                                    Min = g.Min(x => x.MaxBid),
                                    Time = g.Key.Time,
                                    Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)

                                };
```

...

```
private class TickAggregationResult
{
    public decimal MaxBid { get; set; }
        public decimal MinBid { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

    }
```

I then create the index and try to Query it:

```
Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(TickAggregation).Assembly, documentStore);


        var session = documentStore.OpenSession();

        var g1 = session.Query<TickAggregationResult>(typeof(TickAggregation).Name);


        var group = session.Query<Tick, TickAggregation>()
                         .Where(x => x.Time > new DateTime(2012, 4, 23) && 
                                     x.Time < new DateTime(2012, 4, 24, 00, 0, 0)
                                  )
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
                                           .AsProjection<TickAggregationResult>();
```

But the group is just empty :(

As you can see I've tried two different Queries, I'm not sure about the difference, can someone explain?

**Now I get an error:** [image]

The group are still empty :(

Let me explain what I'm trying to accomplish in pure sql:

```
select min(Ask), count(*) as TickCount from Ticks 
where Time between '2012-04-23' and '2012-04-24)
```

Comment: Continued here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853783/map-reduce-in-ravendb-update-1
The answer below, that strangely enough was rewarded as useful will not be accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you would work with Map/reduce

```
 from row in rows where row.Time > new DateTime(2012, 4, 23) && row.Time < new DateTime(2012, 4, 24, 00, 0, 0)
```

Create a map reduce index that incorporates the time as part of the group by key, then you can query on that.